# Access ".local" domain name from Docker conatiner without having Avahi installed inside

Tags: docker, networking, mdns, proxmox, avahi

The setup is: Proxmox Host, 1 Linux VM with reverse proxy in docker, 1 Linux VM with webapp in docker.

Goal is to be able to access webapp from reverse proxy using avahi ".local" hostname.

I installed avahi-daemon to both VMs and it works when I ping hosts between VMs, but when I try to access Linux VM with webapp from reverse proxy docker - then it cannot resolve the hostname.

Is it possible to access ".local" hostname without installing avahi-daemon inside of docker container?